# How do I make a Discord bot react to the last message of someone I tagged?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a js Discord bot that will custom react to the last message of the person I had mentioned within a server. I've only tried my hand at javascript for the past day, so I apologize for the noobness. I tried looking for similar solutions and applying logic to no avail. This is the idea

```
Example: 
> User1: I just ran a marathon!
> User2: !goodjob @User1
> (Bot reacts to 'I just ran a marathon' with multiple reactions like :happy: :1thumbsup: and/or a custom react)
```

Here is what I have so far, however this only makes the bot react to the person who initiated the command (without the 3 lines that start with # that I put now in the example)

```
if (cmdName === 'goodjob') {
  let mention = message.mentions.users.first();
  #function getUserFromMention(mention){
  #const matches = mention.match(/^<@!?(\d+)>$/);
  #const id = matches[1];
  message.react('<:emoji:ID>');
  message.react('<:emoji:ID>');
  message.react('<:emoji:ID>');
}
})
});
```

I am not very skilled so I probably messed up the logic somewhere. If the solution was elsewhere I'm sorry! Any and all guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, to make sure the user can write into other channels without breaking it, you can't use the lastMessageID property. So you have to get the last N messages and check of the author, reverse. You can do it with the [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) of the [MessageManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager)

```
message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {
    let mention = message.mentions.users.first();
    const lastUserMessages = messages.filter(v =>  v.author.id === mention.id);
    if (!lastUserMessages) {
        message.reply('This user didn\'t wrote something the last 100 message');
        return;
    }
    const lastUserMessage = lastUserMessages.last();
    if (!lastUserMessage) {
        message.reply('This user didn\'t wrote something the last 100 message');
        return;
    }

    lastUserMessage.react('<:emoji:ID>');
    
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted thank you so much!